# Intercepting queries to a database

Tags: java, database, hibernate, interceptor

So I'm trying to intercept calls made to a database. Right now I have a java program which listens for notifications (calls made by various programs). I'm trying to extend this to analyse queries made by one of these programs to the database, which uses the Hibernate ORM.

I'm looking at the Hibernate Interceptor and that seems quite interesting. How could I integrate the Interceptor into my program? I'm not sure how I can use it to connect with the other programs to listen for calls. Or would the Listener be a better choice?

Thanks, Harry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Integrate Hibernate interceptor in your program, you have to follow these steps:

1. Create a class which extends hibernate's EmptyInterceptor.
2. Implement the methods which are relevant to your requirement.
3. Set it to the Configuration, as

   Configuration cfg = new Configuration();

   cfg.setInterceptor(new YourInterceptor());

Comment: Thanks! I've looked into EmptyInterceptor and that seems fairly straightforward. I'll only need a few of the methods I think. Where would I put the configuration stuff though? Is this in my initial program (where I make the connections to other programs and initialised the notification listener) or in a separate config file? Sorry, I've never used Hibernate before.

Comment: @You will do it in your initial program, where you will read the configuration file(hibernate.cfg.xml) then set the interceptor before creating a sessionFactory.

Comment: for your info go through this small example http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/firstexample.shtml

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for a proxy JDBC driver. These wrap a normal JDBC driver and log what is going on.

One example is [log4jdbc](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/), I'm sure there are others.

The good thing about these is that you don't need to change your program, just the name of the JDBC driver it uses.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into the Hibernate Interceptor first since that seems simpler and if that doesn't work out I'll try this approach. Appreciate the advice.